# R : Plotting a point on the Y axis when the X axis is using a log scale

Tags: r, plot

I'm making a plot in R I'd like to have a symbol appear at a specific point (say, alpha) on my y axis. My x axis uses a log-scale so I don't think I can use the xy coordinates (0, alpha) to plot the point (I may be wrong).

I've tried something like this:

```
W.range <- range(W)
Z.range <- range(Z1, Z2)
# Draw Empty Graph 
plot(W.range, Z.range, type="n", log="x")
# First Curve
lines(W, Z1, type="l", lty=1, lwd=1.5, col=1)
# Second Curve
lines(W, Z2, type="l", lty=2, lwd=1.5, col=2)
# Plot Single Point on vertical axis at level alpha (for some constant alpha)
points(x=0, y=alpha, pch=1, col=1)
```

However, I get errors relating to the x=0 coordinate. Advice? As always, I appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual error (and, preferably, the values W, Z1, and Z2 so that we can reproduce it) ETA: also `alpha`, please

Comment: You need to deal with this issue: log(0) == -Inf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work, subbing in your own data as appropriate:

```
# Example data and plot
x <- y <- 1:100
alpha <- 44
plot(x,y, log="x", type="l")    

# Add point
points(x = 10^(par("usr")[1]), 
       y = alpha, 
       pch = 16, cex=1.3, col = "red", las = 1,
       xpd = TRUE) # controls whether or not pts straddling the axis are clipped
```

[image]

To understand what I did here, have a look at [`?par`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/par.html), which I use here both to query and to set graphical parameters.

In particular, here is the description of `par("usr")`, from the help file linked above:

> ```
> ‘usr’ A vector of the form ‘c(x1, x2, y1, y2)’ giving the extremes
>       of the user coordinates of the plotting region.  When a
>       logarithmic scale is in use (i.e., ‘par("xlog")’ is true, see
>       below), then the x-limits will be ‘10 ^ par("usr")[1:2]’.
>       Similarly for the y-axis.
> ```

The x-coordinates returned by `usr` are in terms of the log-transformed values of x. Thus, to get a point placed on the y-axis, you need to give it an x coordinate **such that it's log (base 10)** is equal to the location of the y-axis, expressed in user coordinates. `par("usr")[1]` gets you the location of the lower limit of the x-axis: `10^(par("usr")[1]` gets you the x-value that will be plotted to just that part of the x-axis.